# Rationale for grouping my list of trauma collocates into nouns and adjectives

Tags: parts-of-speech, lemmas

*Context*: I have a dataset of words within a 5-word window of trauma (i.e., trauma collocates) and they've been parsed into parts of speech (nouns, adjectives, verbs, etc.). I am wanting to look at the nouns for my analyses, and potentially the adjectives to see if the severity ratings of the word meanings have changed over time.

*Problem*: I have no linguistic background and I'm unsure how to search for papers that might help me form a rationale for choosing nouns, for example.

*Question*: Does anyone have any advice/ can anyone point me in the right direction to some papers which might help me form my case? I have seen researchers provide the fact that they're primarily wanting to look at content words as reason for choosing nouns...I remember from a Prof that nouns provide the greatest lexical diversity, but that's about it.

Comment: You say the dataset of words has been parsed into parts of speech. How? A great deal depends on the reliability of that parsing, in context. English words can be treated as any part of speech, in context, and you're trying to pull context out of the data. Be very careful what assumptions have been made in the parsing, since they'll color your results. Consult a linguist, if possible.

Comment: Thank you! Although not a linguist, I'm collaborating with a computational linguist on this project. They first lemmatised the corpus (and lower-cased, removed stop words). Then, the collocates were extracted. I've matched those collocates with the Warriner norms dataset (which has been compiled by linguists and rated by US people) and then this list of lemmas has been parsed using Spacy. In fact, all of the steps were done using https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features

Comment: So that I know which questions to ask the person who parsed the corpus, what things should I look out for and what assumptions should I be careful of making? As far as I understand there's a model used for parsing pos? I'm not sure how the app spacy fits into this.